# Keeping Objects in Memory

Tags: cache, memory, oop

I have built a WordPress plugin using classes. Each project class is created for a specific user. I want to do three things:

- Keep the project object in memory for that user between his or her requests.
- Delete it once the user signs out or after a certain expiration time.
- Delete and recreate if user edits the project information (through a form) for that object.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for [Transients](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API).

In WordPress, transients are short-lived data objects.  By default, they're persisted to the database using WordPress' built-in WP_Object_Cache object.  However, you can use a variety of caching plugins ([Batcache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/batcache/) is an outstanding one that works with Memcached) to store Transients in memory.

To set a transient, call `set_transient( 'a unique name', 'the data value', 'time in seconds until it disappears' );`

Your situation is working with a project object.  Here's what you'd do:

```
function get_project( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! $project = get_transient( 'project_' . $user_id ) ) {
        // get_transient() returns false if the value is expired or doesn't exist.
        $project = new Project( $user_id );

        // Set the transient so that it lives for an hour
        set_transient( 'project_' . $user_id, $project, 3600 );
    }

    return $project;
}
```

Then, in your code, you can call `get_project()` whenever you need to reference the current project.  If it exists in the cache, you'll use the cached version.  If it doesn't, you can build a new instance and save it to the cache.  There's a lot more you'll need to do if you want to manipulate the object after you've retrieved it (and have those manipulations persist in the cache), but that's an exercise I leave to you.